# Try/Catch didn't catch WebException

Tags: c#, mono

I built a .NET Mono application that uploads text files every minute to a server.
In my opinion, the best way to avoid crashing the application is using a try-catch around the upload code, so unexpected errors are caught.

And always it runs correctly for about 2 days, and after that, it suddenly crashes. I'm looking for the cause already for a few weeks but can't find it.

The error I got is:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: Request aborted   at
> System.Net.FtpWebRequest.CheckIfAborted() [0x00000] in :0   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.set_Sate (RequestState value)
> [0x00000] in :0   at
> System.Net.FtpWebRequest.ProcessRequest(RequestState value) [0x00000]
> in <filename:0 unknown>:   at System.Threading.Thread.StartUnsafe ()
> [0x00000] in <filename:0 unknown>:

Answer (score 1):

There's probably nothing wrong with your television set, I mean, your code.

The problem is Mono's FtpWebRequest implementation which is not very robust (poorly handles timeouts at various stages of FTP conversation). I did an analysis of similar case and posted my findings there:

[Mono for Android / MonoTouch System.Net.WebException: Request aborted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16058943/mono-for-android-monotouch-system-net-webexception-request-aborted)

Your case, while not identical, points to the common "bag" of issues with Mono's FtpWebRequest.

Answer (score 0):

Such errors are really hard to find. 
You said that you run this function in a thread. So I guess it's called from the `while` loop and than `Thread.Sleep(1000*60);` or as `fire and forget`. The reason could be, that the function is not finished before the next call or `FtpWebRequest` is still not closed and it is doesn't matter, that it runs at different context.

I had similar problems and here is what you can try:

1) Make `FtpWebRequest request` global and check if it still alive before the function call.

2) Call the garbage collector at the function end:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Please let me know if that works.

Comment: I made a screenshot of the line on the moment the exception occured. http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/16/schermafdrukvan20130220.png/